# How to stop records coming back if relationship doesn't exist (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm trying to stop 'addons' coming back in the AddonGroup if it doesn't have a 'productAddon'.

Is there a way this can be achieved?

**Current Code:**

```
$addonGroups = AddonGroup::whereIn("id", $addonGroups)
                            ->whereHas(['addons.productAddon' => function ($query) use ($customise) {
                                $query->where('product_reference', $customise->package_reference);
                            }])
                            ->with('addons')
                            ->with(['addons.productAddon' => function ($query) use ($customise) {
                                $query->where('product_reference', $customise->package_reference);
                            }])
                            ->with('addons.removals')
                            ->get()->each(function($addonGroup) {
                                foreach ($addonGroup->addons as $key => $value) {
                                    if ($value["image_key"]) {
                                        $value["image_key"] = env("AWS_UPLOADS_URL") . $value["image_key"];
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

**'addons':**

```
public function addons() {
    return $this->hasMany("App\Addon", "addon_group_id", "id")->where('active', 1);
}
```

**'productAddon':**

```
public function productAddon() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\ProductAddon", "addon_id", "id")->without('product');
}
```

Error with current solution:

```
Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of coffee and running multiple tests, I have finally answered my own question and came up with this solution:

```
    $addonGroups = AddonGroup::whereIn("id", $addonGroups)
                        ->with(["addons" => function ($query) use ($customise) {
                            $query->whereHas("productAddon", function ($builder) use ($customise) {
                                $builder->where('product_reference', $customise->package_reference);
                            })
                            ->with('productAddon', 'removals');
                        }])
                        ->get();
```